# Sails.js create two models at once

Tags: sails.js

I am starting to play around with Sailsjs and enjoying it quite a lot.
However I was wondering how could I create an instance of an Account model when an instance of a User model is created.

I came up with this but doesn't feel quite right to create an Account from within the User model.

User.js (the model):

```
afterCreate: function (user, cb){
    //Create account
    Account.create({
        owner_id: user.id,
        uid: (+new Date()).toString(36)
    }).done(function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Could not create account. Error: ' + err);
            cb( err );
        }else{
            cb (null, user);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with creating one model from within another as you've done. Just a couple of things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure you don't create loops by creating Users in an `Account.afterCreate` method.
2. The callback from `afterCreate` only takes one argument (`err`), to be used when there's an error. You won't be able to access your newly created User via this method.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Didn't know about the callback argument!